# Types complex vs int

Tags: python, types, int

```
a = int(input("Please enter the value of a: "))
b = int(input("Please enter the value of b: "))
c = int(input("Please enter the value of c: "))

root_1 = (-b + ((b**2) - 4*a*c)**0.5) / 2*a
root_2 = (-b - ((b**2) - 4*a*c)**0.5) / 2*a

if root_1 < 0 or root_2 < 0:
   root = "No real roots"
elif root_1  > 0 or root_2 > 0:
   root = "Two real roots"
elif root_1 == 0 or root_2 == 0:
   root = "One real root"
print("The values you entered have", root)
```

Hi am having problems with complex and int's giving me an error. Is there a solution to this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What problem are you having?  Where do you use `complex`?  What is the error?

Comment: TypeError: unorderable types: complex() < int() this is the error I get. I'm trying to create a program that will tell the user how many real roots their input values are equal to using the quadratic formula.

Comment: When I entered a=2, b =2 and c=2 the result is a complex number and gives the error that I pasted in the above message.

Comment: You should check if `b^2 - 4*a*c` is larger than 0, instead of the roots.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll give that a go.(I should have know that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole problem is in the logic you are implementing to decide what is the result of the equation....

You are assuming this is the term discriminating the roots in the  [quadratic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation):
**root_1**  and **root_2**

but this is what is telling you about real roots or not:

```
(b**2) - 4*a*c)
```

that is called discriminant

and is calculated as

[image]

if this `(b**2) - 4*a*c)`  is positive then the square root is a real number, but if the expression is negative then the square root will produce an imaginary number...

[image]